# how to add target="_blank" to markItUp plugin

Tags: target, markitup

**What I am trying to do:**

It appears that by default when you use the link option in [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) to add a link, then clicking on the link opens it in the same page.

**What I have tried:**

I looked at the sets.js file and found the following line:

```
{name:'Link', key:'L', openWith:'<a href="[![Link:!:http://]!]"(!( title="[![Title]!]")!)>', closeWith:'</a>', placeHolder:'Your text to link...' }
```

I tried adding `target:'_blank'` (see below) which didn't work:

```
{name:'Link',target:'_blank', key:'L', openWith:'<a href="[![Link:!:http://]!]"(!( title="[![Title]!]")!)>', closeWith:'</a>', placeHolder:'Your text to link...' }
```

Can someone please help out in getting this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what i was doing wrong. The following works:

```
{name:'Link', key:'L', openWith:'<a href="[![Link:!:http://]!]"(!( title="[![Title]!]")!) target="_blank">', closeWith:'</a>', placeHolder:'Your text to link...' },
```